# HtmlHelper to display a named property dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a collection of View Model objects with several date fields.  These fields track status update times.  Im attempting to use a list view to show the View Models in a table, but only show 1 of the date properties based on the name of the desired property.  Is it possible to dynamically display a model field from a collection based on the name of the property?  If so, how?

Thanks

```
class OrderViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId {get; set;}
    public string DateFieldToDisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date1 {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Date2 {get; set;}
    public DateTime? Date3 {get; set;}
}
```

The following is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</p>
   <p>@Html.DisplayFor(item.DateFieldToDisplayName )</p> *****
   // This is the problem.  I would like whatever property name the DateFieldToDisplayName
   // property contains to display its value e.g. DateFieldToDisplayName = "Date1" => give 
   // the value of item.Date1

}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `if (item.DateFieldToDisplayName == "Date1") { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Date1) } else if {...`

Comment: Theres about 10 dates tbh, I was hoping for something more elegant than a large switch statement :).  Thanks for your reply

Comment: If the value of `DateFieldToDisplayName` matches exactly one of the `DateTime` ("Date", Date2" etc) you can use `@Html.Display(item.DateFieldToDisplayName)`

Comment: Hi Stephen, thats what I thought was possible and Ive tried it to no avail.  The value of DateFieldToDisplayName matches the actual date fields name but its not doing anything :(

Comment: Tested and it works for me. If `item.DateFieldToDisplayName = "Date1" then `@Html.Display(item.DateFieldToDisplayName)` translates to @Html.Display("Date1") which will display the value of the `Date1` property - note its `Display()` not `DisplayFor()`

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I still cant get it to work.  I had thought it was pagedlist causing some issues and rolled all of that out to just work with IEnumerables.  No luck.  Tbh Im a bit pushed for time on this so Ime going to have to go with the switch lol

Comment: @Matt... in order to have the Switch a bit more elegant... you can create a Razor helper... so that your table can be clean.